# Will this cable work for wiring my house to router

Tags: ethernet, cables

Will this cable be ok?  I purchased a 100' role of UTP Cat 6.  I will place it in 1" conduit when it goes outside but it will be be bare as it crosses through the basement and maybe over a few electric wires. The Verizon guy put my router in the garage and I would like to move it to the center of the home.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00WD017BG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00WD017BG)

Comment: This will probably get closed, but I would personally use sheilded cat6 (STP) especially if you are running the wires anywhere near electric wires or electronics.. Using UTP, your chances for data errors will be much higher than if you used STP.

Comment: UTP is fine. The design of the system very effectively rejects noise, since it ignores any signal common to the two wires in a pair, and only looks at the difference between them, which is where the data is put in. I have had a lot of UTP connected to switches that report error rates running next to power wires and have never had a problem from that. Actual problems usually result from wire abuse.

Answer (score 2):

Running in outside conduit, that is utterly unsuitable cable.

All outside conduits are DEFINED as wet locations. In practice, nearly all of them are, at least some of the time. Many have standing water in some part of them all the time.

Interior type patch cable (such as what you show) may work for a while, but will commonly fail since it is not designed to be exposed to water (or submerged in it.)

Interior type in-wall cable will also typically fail in wet service.

At minimum you need some sort of exterior-rated network cable. In my experience this is often or commonly "direct burial" rated, though I never advise using it that way - but it can be a useful search term, and often costs no more than non-direct burial exterior cable.

My personal preference runs strongly to fiber optics for runs between buildings, but that is likely a bit more than you'll want to take on.

Comment: I can run whatever works since I'm putting in the conduit and cable.  The goal, here, is to move the modem from the garage to the interior of the house. Coax already runs to the location from the ONT so all I have to do to connect the modem is run an eithernet from the location to the ONT.  Are you saying I can run fiber instead?  I have 100' role of that as well.

Comment: ...if you have terminated fiber or can terminate fiber, and have devices at each end (typically switches) that have SFP or XFP ports, and SPFs or XFPs appropriate to the fiber type and termination, sure. Also, **the fiber cable needs to be exterior rated cable** for the same reason a wire cable does. Which I'd bet a 100 foot roll is not, unless it's the end of a much longer roll.